# i've got error during making metronome in python

Tags: python, interface, window, metronome

I tried this code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from winsound import Beep


class Metronome:
    """Create Metronome app with class instance."""

    def __init__(self,root,beats):
        """initiate default values for class and call interface()."""


        self.root=root
        self.beats=beats

        self.start=False
        self.bpm=0
        self.count=0
        self.beat=0
        self.time=0

        self.var=StringVar()
        self.var.set(self.count)

        self.interface()


     def interface(self):

         frame=Frame()
         frame.pack()

         entry=Entry(frame,width=8,justify="center")
         entry.insert(0,"60")
             entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="E")

         spinbox=Spinbox(frame,width=5,values=self.beats,wrap=True)
         spinbox.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="E")

         label_bpm=Label(frame,text="BPM:")
         label_bpm.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")

         label_time=Label(frame,text="Time:")
         label_time.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,sticky="W")

         label_count=Label(frame,textvariable=self.var,font=("Arial",30))
         label_count.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)

         button_start=Button(frame,text="Start",width=10,height=2,
         command=lambda:self.start_counter(entry,spinbox))
         button_start.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,sticky="W")

         button_stop=Button(frame,text="Stop",width=10,height=2,
         command=lambda:self.stop_counter())
         button_stop.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,sticky="E")

    def start_counter(self,entry,spinbox):
        if not self.start:
            try:
                self.bpm=int(entry.get())
            except ValueError:
                self.bpm=60
            else:
                if self.bpm>300:
                    self.bpm=300

            self.start=True
            self.counter(spinbox)

    def stop_counter(self):
        self.start=False

    def counter(self,spinbox):
        if self.beat==6:
            self.time=int(((60/(self.bpm/.5)-0.1))*1000)
        else:
            self.time=int((60/self.bpm-0.1)*1000)

        self.count +=1
        self.var.set(self.count)

        if self.count==1:
            Beep(880,100)
        elif self.count >=self.beat:
            self.count=0
            Beep(440,100)
        else:
            Beep(440,100)


        self.root.after(self.time,lambda :self.count(spinbox))


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Metronome")

    beats=["4/4","6/8","2/4","3/4"]
    Metronome(root,beats)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

But I got an error that says

```
"line 29 def interface(self):
                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: seems to be 5 spaces not 4

Comment: All your methods need to be at the same level of indentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the diffrence level of indentation! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is about the spaces and tabs, it might work better like this :

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from winsound import Beep


class Metronome:
    """Create Metronome app with class instance."""

    def __init__(self, root, beats):
        """initiate default values for class and call interface()."""

        self.root = root
        self.beats = beats

        self.start = False
        self.bpm = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.beat = 0
        self.time = 0

        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set(self.count)

        self.interface()


    def interface(self):

        frame=Frame()
        frame.pack()

        entry=Entry(frame,width=8,justify="center")
        entry.insert(0,"60")
        entry.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="E")

        spinbox=Spinbox(frame,width=5,values=self.beats,wrap=True)
        spinbox.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="E")

        label_bpm=Label(frame,text="BPM:")
        label_bpm.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")

        label_time=Label(frame,text="Time:")
        label_time.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,sticky="W")

        label_count=Label(frame,textvariable=self.var,font=("Arial",30))
        label_count.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)

        button_start=Button(frame,text="Start",width=10,height=2,
        command=lambda:self.start_counter(entry,spinbox))
        button_start.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,sticky="W")

        button_stop=Button(frame,text="Stop",width=10,height=2,
        command=lambda:self.stop_counter())
        button_stop.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,sticky="E")

    def start_counter(self,entry,spinbox):
        if not self.start:
            try:
                self.bpm=int(entry.get())
            except ValueError:
                self.bpm=60
            else:
                if self.bpm>300:
                    self.bpm=300

            self.start=True
            self.counter(spinbox)

    def stop_counter(self):
        self.start=False

    def counter(self,spinbox):
        if self.beat==6:
            self.time=int(((60/(self.bpm/.5)-0.1))*1000)
        else:
            self.time=int((60/self.bpm-0.1)*1000)

        self.count +=1
        self.var.set(self.count)

        if self.count==1:
            Beep(880,100)
        elif self.count >=self.beat:
            self.count=0
            Beep(440,100)
        else:
            Beep(440,100)


        self.root.after(self.time,lambda :self.counter(spinbox))


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Metronome")

    beats=["4/4","6/8","2/4","3/4"]
    Metronome(root,beats)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Also there was an error on the 90th line it was written

```
self.root.after(self.time,lambda :self.count(spinbox))
```

instead of

```
self.root.after(self.time,lambda :self.counter(spinbox))
```